# using mutex or another synchronisation methods for C and Java code through JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

Is there any way I can synchronize the data(data sharing) between C and Java code with JNI using mutex or any other methods.

Please let me know if you have any documentation about the methods for data sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any lock you prefer in C and make it available to Java via JNI. 
You can do the reverse as well, calling a method in Java from C to use the lock.

I would do it natively in the framework which created the thread.

Comment: What I was asking is, I want to read something on the native code and write in Java code. Is it is possible to synchronize this.

Comment: Yes. Provided you use the same lock(s) on both sides.  You could also look at lock free ways to do this if performance is critical (but 10x harder to get right)